# SQL Help - Finding order before current records timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Forgive me if this question is confusing:
I have a patient level data with records created by Nurses and doctors.

For each patient the doctor inputs a Target daily value for each patient. The doctor may modify this target multiple time

During the course of the day the nurse enters a value with the goal of total value being equal to the target set by the doctor.

I'm trying to write a query that 
1. For each patient return every value entered by the nurse and look for the most recent doctor order made prior to the nurse's recording his/her value.

The following is the SQL I've been working on

```
--*********************************************-***************************************************
-- As of 10/11/2018 - Runtime = 1:40 min
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME

-- Change the following 2 variables to select a different date range for     patient attribution
SET @StartDate =  '2018-03-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2018-10-31 00:00:00.000'

--*************************************************

Select Distinct

                                            results.LOCATION_ABBR
                                            ,results.PROTOCOL_NAME
                                            ,results.PROV_NAME
                                            ,results.MRN
                                            ,results.OSU_CSN
                                            ,results.PAT_NAME
                                            ,results.AGE_YEARS,
                                            results.gender,
                                            results.Race,
                                            results.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,
                                            results.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,
                                            results.OrderDate,
                                            results.TF_ORDERED
                                     --     ,results.TF_Datetime
                                            ,results.TF_Date
                                            ,results.TF_Time
                                            ,results.TF_Daily
                                            ,SUM(results.TF_Daily) OVER     (partition by results.OSU_CSN, results.TF_Date) AS Daily_TF_Total_v2
                                            ,results.Total_Required
                                            ,results.Daily_TF_Total
                       --                   ,results.First_TF
                       --                   ,results.Last_TF
From (

                                            Select Distinct
                                            OSU_Data.LOCATION_ABBR
                                            ,OSU_Data.PROTOCOL_NAME
                                            ,OSU_Data.PROV_NAME
                                            ,OSU_Data.MRN
                                            ,OSU_Data.OSU_CSN
                                            ,OSU_Data.PAT_NAME
                                            ,OSU_Data.AGE_YEARS,
                                            OSU_Data.gender,
                                            Race.PatRace as Race,
                                            OSU_Data.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,
                                            OSU_Data.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,
                                            OSU_Data.DATE_USED,
                                            OSU_Data.OrderDate,
                                            OSU_Data.TF_ORDERED
                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Datetime
                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Date
                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Time
                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Daily


                                            ,Max(cast(OSU_Data.TF_ORDERED as     numeric(9,2))) OVER (partition by OSU_Data.OSU_CSN, OSU_Data.DATE_USED) AS     Total_Required
                                            ,SUM(TF_Daily.TF_Daily) OVER     (partition by OSU_Data.OSU_CSN, TF_Daily.TF_Date) AS Daily_TF_Total
                                            ,row_number() over (partition by     OSU_Data.OSU_CSN order by TF_Daily.TF_Datetime) First_TF
                                            ,row_number() over (partition by OSU_Data.OSU_CSN order by TF_Daily.TF_Datetime desc) Last_TF
                                     --     ,LAG(OSU_Data.OrderDate) OVER (ORDER BY OSU_Data.OSU_CSN,OSU_Data.OrderDate,TF_Datetime) PreviousTFOrderDT
                                     --     ,LEAD(OSU_Data.OrderDate) OVER     (ORDER BY OSU_Data.OSU_CSN,OSU_Data.OrderDate,TF_Datetime) NextTFOrderDT



                                     From

                                            (



                                            Select

                                              preOSU_Data.Orderid

                                            ,preOSU_Data.PROTOCOL_ID

                                            ,preOSU_Data.PROTOCOL_NAME

                                            ,preOSU_Data.LOCATION_ABBR

                                            ,preOSU_Data.PROV_NAME

                                            ,preOSU_Data.PAT_ID

                                            ,preOSU_Data.MRN

                                            ,preOSU_Data.OSU_CSN

                                            ,preOSU_Data.PAT_NAME

                                            ,preOSU_Data.AGE_YEARS

                                            ,preOSU_Data.gender

                                            ,Race.PatRace

                                            ,preOSU_Data.OrderDate

                                            -- ,preOSU_Data.TF_GoalHr

                                            ,preOSU_Data.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME

                                            ,preOSU_Data.HOSP_DISCH_TIME                                                         

                                             ,preOSU_Data."YEAR USED"

                                            ,preOSU_Data."MONTH USED"

                                            ,preOSU_Data.DATE_USED

                                            ,preOSU_Data."For Sorting"

                                            ,preOSU_Data.TF_ORDERED



                                     From





                                                          (Select Distinct



                                                                           ORDERS.ORDER_ID as Orderid

                                                                           ,CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID

                                                                       ,CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_NAME

                                                                        ,CLARITY_LOC.LOCATION_ABBR

                                                                       ,CLARITY_SER.PROV_NAME

                                                                       ,PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ID

                                                                           ,V_PAT_FACT.PAT_MRN_ID as MRN

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID as OSU_CSN

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.PAT_NAME

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.AGE_YEARS

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.SEX_NAME as gender

                                                                       ,ORDER_INST as OrderDate

                                                                       ,DATEPART(HOUR, ORDER_INST) as TF_GoalHr

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.HOSP_DISCH_TIME                                                         

                                                                       ,YEAR(ORDER_INST)                                                        "YEAR USED"

                                                                       ,DATENAME(MONTH, ORDER_INST)                                                                  "MONTH USED"

                                                                        ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),DAY(ORDER_INST))     DATE_USED

                                                                        ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),1)                       "For Sorting"



                                                                        ,ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORD_QUEST_RESP as TF_ORDERED



                                                                       ,Max(ORDER_INST) OVER (partition by PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),DAY(ORDER_INST))) AS Last_DailyTFGoalTimestamp

                                                          From

                                                                       PAT_ENC_HSP

                                                                       ,ORDERS

                                                                       ,ORDER_PROC

                                                                       ,ORDER_SMARTSET

                                                                       ,CL_PRL_SS

                                                                       ,ZC_PAT_SERVICE

                                                                       ,ORD_SPEC_QUEST

                                                                       ,CL_QQUEST

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT

                                                                       ,CLARITY_SER

                                                                       ,CLARITY_ADT

                                                                       ,CLARITY_DEP

                                                                       ,CLARITY_LOC

                                                                       ,ZC_PATIENT_RACE



                                                          Where

                                                                        (PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = ORDER_SMARTSET.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

                                                                       AND ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORDER_SMARTSET.ORDER_ID

                                                                       AND ORDER_PROC.ORDER_PROC_ID=ORDER_SMARTSET.ORDER_ID

                                                                       AND ORDER_SMARTSET.SS_PRL_ID=CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID

                                                                       AND ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORDER_ID                                             

                                                                        AND ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORD_QUEST_ID = CL_QQUEST.QUEST_ID)

                                                                       and PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = CLARITY_ADT.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

                                                                       and CLARITY_ADT.DEPARTMENT_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID

                                                                        and CLARITY_DEP.REV_LOC_ID = CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID

                                                                       and PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ID = V_PAT_FACT.PAT_ID

                                                                       and ORDER_PROC.AUTHRZING_PROV_ID = CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID



                                                                        and PAT_ENC_HSP. HOSP_ADMSN_TIME between @StartDate and @EndDate

                                                                       AND CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID = 799

                                                                       AND CAST(CL_QQUEST.QUEST_ID as varchar(25)) = '101960'





                                                          UNION

                                                                       Select Distinct



                                                                       ORDERS.ORDER_ID as Orderid

                                                                       ,CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID

                                                                       ,CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_NAME

                                                                        ,CLARITY_LOC.LOCATION_ABBR

                                                                       ,CLARITY_SER.PROV_NAME

                                                                       ,PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ID

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.PAT_MRN_ID as MRN

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID as OSU_CSN

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.PAT_NAME

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.AGE_YEARS

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT.SEX_NAME as gender

                                                                       ,ORDER_INST as OrderDate

                                                                       ,DATEPART(HOUR, ORDER_INST) as TF_GoalHr

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME

                                                                        ,PAT_ENC_HSP.HOSP_DISCH_TIME                                                         

                                                                       ,YEAR(ORDER_INST)        "YEAR USED"

                                                                       ,DATENAME(MONTH, ORDER_INST)                                                                  "MONTH USED"

                                                                        ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),DAY(ORDER_INST))     DATE_USED

                                                                        ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),1)                       "For Sorting"

                                                                        ,ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORD_QUEST_RESP as TF_ORDERED





                                                                       ,Max(ORDER_INST) OVER (partition by PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ORDER_INST),MONTH(ORDER_INST),DAY(ORDER_INST))) AS Last_DailyTFGoalTimestamp

                                                          From

                                                                       PAT_ENC_HSP

                                                                       ,ORDERS

                                                                       ,ORDER_PROC

                                                                       ,ORDER_METRICS

                                                                       ,CL_PRL_SS

                                                                       ,ZC_PAT_SERVICE

                                                                       ,ORD_SPEC_QUEST

                                                                       ,CL_QQUEST

                                                                       ,V_PAT_FACT

                                                                       ,CLARITY_SER

                                                                       ,CLARITY_ADT

                                                                       ,CLARITY_DEP

                                                                       ,CLARITY_LOC

                                                          Where

                                                                  (PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = ORDER_METRICS.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

                                                                       and ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_ID

                                                                       AND ORDER_PROC.ORDER_PROC_ID=ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_ID

                                                                       AND ORDER_METRICS.PRL_ORDERSET_ID=CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID

                                                                       AND ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORDER_ID                                             

                                                                        AND ORD_SPEC_QUEST.ORD_QUEST_ID = CL_QQUEST.QUEST_ID)

                                                                       and PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = CLARITY_ADT.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

                                                                       and CLARITY_ADT.DEPARTMENT_ID = CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID

                                                                        and CLARITY_DEP.REV_LOC_ID = CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID

                                                                       and PAT_ENC_HSP.PAT_ID = V_PAT_FACT.PAT_ID

                                                                       and ORDER_PROC.AUTHRZING_PROV_ID = CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID

                                                                       and PAT_ENC_HSP. HOSP_ADMSN_TIME between @StartDate and @EndDate

                                                                       AND  CL_PRL_SS.PROTOCOL_ID = 799

                                                                       AND CAST(CL_QQUEST.QUEST_ID as varchar(25)) = '101960'
                                                                                            ) as preOSU_Data

                                                                                            --********************************************************

                                                                                            -- PATIENT_RACE has multiple lines for some patients

                                                                                            -- Added the following to return Line 1 from Patient_Race

                                                                                            Inner Join(

                                                                                                                 SELECT DISTINCT

                                                                                                                 PATIENT_RACE.PAT_ID,

                                                                                                                 ZC_PATIENT_RACE.NAME as PatRace

                                                                                                                 FROM PATIENT_RACE, ZC_PATIENT_RACE

                                                                                                                 WHERE

                                                                                                                 PATIENT_RACE.PATIENT_RACE_C = ZC_PATIENT_RACE.PATIENT_RACE_C

                                                                                                                and LINE = 1

                                                                                            ) as Race on preOSU_Data.PAT_ID = Race.PAT_ID

                                                          WHERE preOSU_Data.OrderDate = Last_DailyTFGoalTimestamp

                                                   --     ORDER BY

                                                   --     preOSU_Data.OSU_CSN

                                                   --     ,preOSU_Data.OrderDate











                                            ) as OSU_Data

                                            --********************************************************

                                            -- PATIENT_RACE has multiple lines for some patients

                                            -- Added the following to return Line 1 from Patient_Race

                                            Inner Join(

                                                                 SELECT DISTINCT

                                                                 PATIENT_RACE.PAT_ID,

                                                                 ZC_PATIENT_RACE.NAME as PatRace

                                                                 FROM PATIENT_RACE, ZC_PATIENT_RACE

                                                                 WHERE

                                                                 PATIENT_RACE.PATIENT_RACE_C = ZC_PATIENT_RACE.PATIENT_RACE_C



                                                                 and LINE = 1

                                            ) as Race on OSU_Data.PAT_ID = Race.PAT_ID



                              --            WHERE



                              --            OSU_Data.OrderDate = OSU_Data.Last_DailyTFGoalTimestamp



                                            --



                                            ---------------------------------------------------------

                                            -- Daily TF given

                                            ---------------------------------------------------------

                                            Inner join

                                                          (

                                                   select distinct

                                                   PATIENT.PAT_NAME,

                                                   PAT_ENC.HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME,

                                                   pat_enc.pat_enc_csn_id,

                                                   IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.recorded_time as TF_Datetime,



                                                   CONVERT (DATE,IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.recorded_time) as TF_Date,

                                                   Format(IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.recorded_time, 'h:mm tt') as TF_Time,

                                                   DATEPART(HOUR, IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.recorded_time) as TF_Hour, 

                                                   isnull(cast(IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.MEAS_VALUE as float),0) as TF_Daily



                                            FROM

                                                   PAT_ENC

                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN PATIENT ON PAT_ENC.PAT_ID = PATIENT.PAT_ID

                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN PAT_ENC_2 ON PAT_ENC.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = PAT_ENC_2.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_PAT_CLASS ON PAT_ENC_2.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = ZC_PAT_CLASS.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C

                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN IP_FLWSHT_REC ON PAT_ENC.INPATIENT_DATA_ID = IP_FLWSHT_REC.INPATIENT_DATA_ID

                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN IP_FLWSHT_MEAS ON IP_FLWSHT_REC.FSD_ID = IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.FSD_ID

                                            where

                                                     PAT_ENC. HOSP_ADMSN_TIME between @StartDate and @EndDate

                                                   and IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.FLO_MEAS_ID = '3043040002'

                                                   -- and IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.FLT



                                            Group by

                                                          PATIENT.PAT_NAME,

                                                   PAT_ENC.HOSP_DISCHRG_TIME,

                                                   PAT_ENC_2.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C,



                                                   pat_enc.pat_enc_csn_id,

                                                   IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.recorded_time,

                                                   IP_FLWSHT_MEAS.MEAS_VALUE



                                                          ) as TF_Daily on OSU_Data.OSU_CSN = TF_Daily.pat_enc_csn_id and TF_Datetime > OSU_Data.OrderDate -- and Osu_Data.TF_GoalHr = TF_Daily.TF_Hour







                                            --**********************************************************





                                            --and TF_Daily.TF_Datetime >=





                                            Group by

                                            OSU_Data.OSU_CSN

                                            ,OSU_Data.OrderDate

                                            ,OSU_Data.DATE_USED

                                            ,TF_Datetime



                                            ,OSU_Data.LOCATION_ABBR

                                            ,OSU_Data.PROTOCOL_NAME

                                            ,OSU_Data.PROV_NAME

                                            ,OSU_Data.MRN

                                            ,OSU_Data.PAT_NAME

                                            ,OSU_Data.AGE_YEARS,

                                            OSU_Data.gender,

                                            Race.PatRace,

                                     --     OSU_Data.Race,

                                            OSU_Data.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,

                                            OSU_Data.HOSP_DISCH_TIME

                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Date

                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Daily

                                            --,TF_Daily2

                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Time

                                            ,TF_Daily.TF_Hour

                                            ,OSU_Data.TF_ORDERED



                                            ) as results

-- Exclusions and Clean-up
Where

results.Total_Required >= 800 
and results.Daily_TF_Total > 0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `group by` creates rows that are unique (you just don't need `select distinct` as well) Also `union` removes duplicate rows, so you probably only need `union all` (which is faster).